# View Last Published Version

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, document-library, script-webpart

I am trying to create a document library, which has a default view of the most recently published major version. If anyone checks-out a document to create a draft, I want other editors to be able to still see the publish

I tried to implement flayman's solution here: [Document Library-Major and Minor Views](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118412/document-library-major-and-minor-views)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    ListTemplateType: 101,
    Templates: {
        OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
            for (var i = ctx.ListData.Row.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                var row = ctx.ListData.Row[i];
                var versionString = row._UIVersionString;
                var versionFloat = parseFloat(versionString);
                if (versionFloat < 1.0) {
                    // this removes any rows that have had no published version yet
                    ctx.ListData.Row.splice(i, 1);
                    continue;
                }

                var versionInt = parseInt(versionFloat);
                versionString = versionInt + '.0';
                // The link doesn't work if there are no minor versions beyond this
                if (versionString == row._UIVersionString) continue;

                var versionBin = versionInt * 512;
                row._UIVersionString = versionString;
                row.FileRef = '/_vti_history/' + versionBin + row.FileRef;
            }
        }
    }
});
})();
</script>
```

Problem is that the reference document link will go to the most recent version e.g. 1.1 not the most recent published version e.g. 1.0. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: In your opinion, what's the diff between the most recent version and the most recent published version?

Comment: The most recent published version has been approved by an approver, while the most recent version has been edited, but not yet approved. I want editors to be able to see the approved published version as default, but also be able to view any current drafts if necessary.